# String tokenization terminates before reading the entire string

Tags: c, string

I've been trying to split a string by whitespace character. The format of the string is `a, b` and I need to split it as `a` and `b`. The code I've written is as below but the loop always terminates before printing the last character.

```
void tokenize(char *str)
{
    int i = 0, k = 0;
    char *ch = malloc(1000);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    while(i < strlen(str))
    {
        if(str[i] == ' ')
        {
            k = 0;
            printf("%s", ch);
            ch = malloc(1000);
            i++;
        }
        else if(str[i] == ',')
            i++;
        else
        {
            ch[k++] = str[i++];
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
q1, q2
q1
```

As it's evident from the output above, it terminates before printing `q2`, a solution to solve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: you need to print ch after the loop (and a \n can be a good idea)

Comment: Hey thanks, but why does the loop terminate before printing?

Comment: you print when you read a space, the sting is not ending with a space so no print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print after the loop as the print is only done when reading a space:

```
#define STRLEN 1024

void tokenize(const char *str)
{
    int i = 0, k = 0;
    free(ch);
    char *ch = malloc(STRLEN);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    while(i < strlen(str))
    {
        if(str[i] == ' ')
        {
            k = 0;
            printf("%s\n", ch);
            ch = malloc(STRLEN);
            i++;
        }
        else if(str[i] == ',')
            i++;
        else
        {
            ch[k++] = str[i++];
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", ch);
    free(ch);
}
```

Comment: Just curious if I add ```if(str[i] == ' ' || i == strlen(str) - 1)``` solve the issue?

Comment: Its leaking memory. Free `ch` after both `printf()`.

Comment: Update done, thanks @H.S.